# Android AlertDialog wont came out for instance

Tags: javascript, android

How do i fix the code???

line 12, 17, 19, 20, 33, 34
annotation problem

and i did make parameter

```html
public int toast;
```

I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 4.2. While looking at the UserManager class I came across the following method:

```html
package com.ds.settings;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TestActivity {

    @Override
    public void TestActivity(String id, String pass) {
        Toast.makeText(this, id+"/"+pass, Toast(private int Toast).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                show();
            }
        });
    }

    void show()
    {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragmentExample();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog"); //"dialog"라는 태그를 갖는 프래그먼트를 보여준다.
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth is all that copy-paste about UserManager about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `TestActivity` must extend `AppCompatActivity` class so that the `onCreate` method could be overriden. Your class isn't using Inheritance or Interface Implementation, that's why `@Override` annotation is throwing error.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Second, your code for showing `Toast` is wrong. This is how you can fix that.

```
    Toast.makeText(this, id+"/"+pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Third, remove `@Override` annotation from the method you're using for showing toast and also rename it to something else because it should not be same as the class name.

```
public void showToast(String id, String pass) {
    Toast.makeText(this, id+"/"+pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```